# Вывод на экран метода

Tags: java

Есть метод `sumCalculate`, который суммирует все элементы массива. Хочу вывести на экран его в `main`, но ошибка. Каким образом вывести его на экран именно в `main` ?
Попробовал создал метод суммы то на экран выводит.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[] = new int[] {10, -6, 5, 8, 58, 5};

    System.out.println(sumCalculate(array, 0);); // Вот эта строка 
    System.out.println(suma(5, 6));
}
public static void sumCalculate(int array[], int sum) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
}

public static int suma(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: И вообще, выводится не метод, а результат его вызова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас метод `sumCalculate(int array[], int sum)` ничего не возвращает. Нужно как-то так:

```
public static int sumCalculate(int array[], int sum ){

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
        sum+=array[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Добавка от [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy):

У вас лишняя точка с запятой в этой строке

```
System.out.println(sumCalculate(array, 0););
```

Должно быть так

```
System.out.println(sumCalculate(array, 0));
```

Comment: А ещё там `;` лишняя у него.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, обновил ответ.

Comment: Qwertiy , LEQADA спасибо во всем разобрался)

Comment: @spingalet, пожалуйста. Кликните на галочку слева от ответа.